# JQuery Not working Cordova 3.1.0 on actual IOS device but works on emulator

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I've been working on this for a long time now and banging my head for the solution for the problem.

I am working with cordova (phonegap) 3.1.0 using the IOS platform. I initially develop an app using the xcode iphone emulator and it works fine. Unfortunately, when I tried to run my app on the ipad the jquery that suppose to trigger the generation of json is not working.

I tried to include the following code but still there is no luck...

```
$.support.cors = true; 
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
```

I currently working with jquery mobile-1.3.2.js

here is the header of my index.html file

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
> ```
>
> ```
> <script> document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
>       function hyperlink(){
>       window.location = "introduction.html";
>       }
> </script>
>
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css">
> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
> ```

and here is my jquery code:

```
$.getJSON(res/json/jsonFile.json, function(data){
    var md5ModName = null;
        for (var property in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            md5ModName = property;
        }
     }
  localStorage['mainJSON'] = JSON.stringify(data[md5ModName]);
});
```

your help will be appreciated :D

Comment: Any error in the log? try using http://jsconsole.com/ and send commands like $("something") to your device and see if its working.

Comment: Somehow the jquery code above is not working. I tried to run purely javascript codes and is working perfectly on the ipad.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem... It turns out to be IOS cordova is very sensitive on the character case of file names.

I was importing

```
res/json/jsonFile.json
```

which the actual file is jsonFIle.json with a capital I.

Anyway, thanks Sirikon for your help!